# Как в Dart узнать тип возвращаемого значения функции, которая передается как параметр?

Tags: flutter, dart

в Dart функцию передают в виде экземпляра класса Function. Выглядит это так:

```
int someFun(Function f) {}
```

Т.е. `f` теории может вернуть любое значение. В котлине всё понятно. Мы видим тип, который вернет переданная функция:

```
fun someFun(f: () -> Int) { val k = f() }
```

Есть ли в dart возможность получить этот самый тип?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так:

```
void someFun(int Function() f) {}
```

А параметры можно задать так:

```
void someFun(void Function(int) f) {}
```

Итог:

```
void someFun(int Function(int) f) {}
```